# Resources and Problems on Generalized Symmetries

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, resource-recommendations, education

There has been some recent buzz around generalized/higher form/categorical(?) symmetries in the physics community. I understand [Seiberg's](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148) papers are a popular resource, and I am aware of [McGreevy's review](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.03045) on the subject in the context of condensed matter. Nonetheless, what are some other resources I might look at if I want to learn about the subject? Specifically, where might I find problems on the subject (e.g., [Andrew Lucas's lecture notes](https://sites.google.com/colorado.edu/andrew-lucas/teaching/p5040s2021?authuser=0) include one fairly introductory problem on the topic)?

Comment: I find it somewhat a countersense to propose closing a request for resources as "opinion based". Come on, addicted-to-closing people. This is undermining the reputation of this site!